# Google Calendar Api React 'gapi not found'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api

I am new to google calendar api and react so I'm sure there is something small I'm missing here.  I cannot import the necessary google api libraries to call "gapi."  I have try to import them like I would do from local libraries but still get the error "gapi is not defined".  I need to use the "gapi" in my component so I don't think I can call and append the script to the body using the componentDidLoad.

```
  // Libraries
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    //...import other libraries

    //import google libraries in order to use "gapi" and call "checkAuth"
   import 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.min.js';
   import 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth';';


    var CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE';

    var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];

    class NewCalendar extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.checkAuth = this.checkAuth.bind(this);
      }

        checkAuth() {
          console.log('checkAuth running...')
          gapi.auth.authorize(   //ISSUE
```

**^issue with the last line**

```
            {
              'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
              'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
              'immediate': true
            }, this.handleAuthResult);
        }
    ...
    }

    export default NewCalendar;
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with similiar issues. Thats how I solved it. In this case you Need to put the window. scope infront. But hopfeully you found a solution until now ;) Want to share this anyway, maybe it's not the best solution but works for me for the Moment.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadApi();
}

loadApi() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.onload = () => { 
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', this.checkAuth.bind(this));
    }
}
```

bye

Comment: yes, this is how I eventually solved it too.  Good to have an answer up here for others too

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to React and JSX but it seems that you might have ideas to answer your problems here:

- [GAPI is not defined - ReactJS - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112947/gapi-is-not-defined-reactjs-google-sheets)
- https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/src/index.js#L33

It seems that import only works for local files, and that you will need to to async load of the gapi (https://jsx.github.io/doc/importref.html)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Place your `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` inside a script tag inside of your `index.html` file, below your meta tag. That should be it.

Then in the browser, refresh the page and in your JavaScript console, you should be able to write out `gapi` and you should be able to see an object like so: `{load: f}`.

That object would be the Google API that is available on the `window` scope of your browser.